# The words that and than

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I heard the following sentence in a video.

> It is always less expensive to prevent the pollution that it is to
>   clean it up.

If it is grammatically correct, can I rewrite the same sentence by only replacing the word that with the word than?

> It is always less expensive to prevent the pollution than it is to
>   clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

### "That" is not correct in the original sentence

"That" should be "than." Perhaps you misheard or there was a sound quality problem that caused the audio to be distorted and sound like "that" instead of "than." Or perhaps the person just made a mistake in speaking (that's very common, too).

Your adjusted sentence is the correct way to write/say it.